# Problem arises in XNA when going between VSC# 2008 to 2010

Tags: c#, xna

My problem is that I have written code in Visual C# for a background for a game that is part of my grade in a class. The background has multiple layers moving at different speeds is how I modified some code... I did this in 2008 version with XNA 3.1 and it worked fine and the background ran like intended. But when I went and ran the exact same code in the 2010 version on XNA 4.0 this error message appeared that states:

"No suitable graphics card found.

Could not find a Direct3D Device that supports the XNA Framework 
HiDef profile.

Verify that a suitable graphics device is installed.

Make sure the desktop is not locked, and that no other application is
running in full screen mode.

Avoid running under Remote Desktop or as a Windows service.

Check the display properties to make sure hardware acceleration is set
to Full."

I understand that is says I need a better graphics card,but i was confused at the fact is worked in 2008 easily... so I went and change my setting to try and fix the problem to no avail. Is my graphic card not good, even though it worked in 2008 consistently? Have anyone else encountered this message and if so how did you fix it? I am wondering how do I make it so that I can run the said background in 2010 version. Appreciate any assistance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many breaking changes between XNA 3 and 4.  I would finish out the project in 3.1 if I were you.  In 4.0:The HiDef profile requires DX10 hardware.  The Reach profile supports older hardware.
This covers how to get to the older profile and what is covered by it.
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160127182039/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/07/19/selecting-reach-vs-hidef.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a better graphics card...  Xna 3.1 uses Shader version 1.2 and Xna 4 uses shader 3 version. Your card doesn't support the correct shader version.